# How to skip a value in highcharts.js?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image: charts]

I have the chart on the left, and I want to convert it to the chart on the right.  Basically, if the data point has a value of 0, I want to delete that data point and connect the previous data point to the next one.  I can't set the value of the data point to null, since the graph will be interrupted in this case.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to rewrite your question in a few more words. It feels very cryptic.

Comment: you have write query to where not equal condition of zero

Comment: if null, I need to connect points https://prnt.sc/j7vfo6

Comment: You need to set connectNulls to be true.  https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.connectNulls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I can't set the value of the data point to null, since the graph will be interrupted in this case.*

You can avoid interrupts if you set [`connectNulls: true`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.connectNulls).